# How to use images in CSS that is used from Jade files rendered via Node.js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pug

I have the following directory structure in one of my Node.js projects:

```
/web
  /views
    /css
      asc.gif
      bg.gif
      desc.gif
      tablesorter.css
    index.jade
    search.jade
  server.js
```

I render `search.jade` file from the `server.js`.

In the `search.jade` file I include the `tablesortes.css` file:

```
style
  include css/tablesorter.css
```

`tablesorter.css` looks like the following:

```
/* tables */
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(desc.gif);
}
```

As you can see, it depends on the .gif files which is located in the same directory.

The problem is that my code doesn't see these .gif files (all other styles from the `tablesorter.css` file works perfectly).

The workaround that I use at this moment is the following code

```
app.use(express.static('views/css'));
```

placed in the `server.js` file, but I wonder is it the appropriate way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution seems simple enough, but using full paths in the CSS could be an alternative.

Either you add the full path manually, or use some processor to do it for you. This could be through a pre-processor of your choice *at compile time* or use a custom-made Jade [filter](http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/) on the include (bottom of [the page](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/))

So perhaps in a code like

```
style
  include:fullpaths-css css/tablesorter.css
```

`fullpaths-css` would be your *just-in-time* processor, maybe based on postcss.